# Rspec objects comparation fails (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I wrote a simple spec to test the **update action** with **invalid attributes**. I expect that the obj attributes remain the same, but for some strange reason the test fails, although the attributes are still the same.

Thanks in advice.

### Spec

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::PatientsController, type: :controller  do

    # ...

    ## 1.2
    # Update patient
    describe "PUT #update patient" do

      let(:patient_attributes) { attributes_for(:patient_for_contact) }

      # Useful variables
      let(:patient_id) { patient_attributes[:patient_id] }
      let(:physio_center_code) { patient_attributes[:physio_center_code] }
      let(:physio_center_id) { PhysioCenter.find_by_code(physio_center_code).id }

      # let! force the method's invocation before each example (not lazy evaluated).
      let!(:patient) { create(:patient, patient_id: patient_id, physio_center_id: physio_center_id) }


      context "with wrong attributes" do

        # invalid attributes with the same :patient_id, :physio_center_code
        let(:invalid_patient_attributes) { attributes_for(:invalid_patient_for_contact, patient_id: patient_id, physio_center_code: physio_center_code) }

        # IT PASSES
        it "respond with 422" do
          put :update, patient: invalid_patient_attributes
          expect(response.status).to eq(422)
        end

        # IT FAILS
        it "doesn't change the attributes of the patient (TO FIX)" do
          put :update, patient: invalid_patient_attributes

          # set variables
          not_updated_patient = Patient.where(patient_id: patient_id, physio_center_id:  physio_center_id).take

          expect(not_updated_patient.attributes).to eq(patient.attributes) #--> FAIL
          # expect(not_updated_patient).to have_attributes(patient.attributes) #--> FAIL
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### Controller

```rb
module Api
  module V1
    class PatientsController < ApplicationController

      before_action :set_physio_center, only: [:create, :update]
      before_action :set_patient, only: :update

      def update
        if @patient
          patient_params.extract!(:patient_id, :physio_center_code)
          if @patient.update_attributes(patient_params)
            render json: {message: "Patient updated"}, status: 204
          else
            render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        end
      end

      protected

      def set_physio_center
        physio_center_code = params[:patient][:physio_center_code]
        # find_by() doesn't raise exception if record_not_found, so i force it if nil
        @physio_center = PhysioCenter.find_by_code(physio_center_code) ||
            raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, message: "Couldn't find PhysioCenter with 'physio_center_code'=#{physio_center_code}.\n")
      end

      def set_patient
        patient_id = params[:patient][:patient_id]
        @patient = Patient.find_by(patient_id: patient_id, physio_center_id: @physio_center.id) ||
            raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, message: "Couldn't find Patient with 'patient_id'=#{patient_id} and 'physio_center_id'=#{@physio_center.id}.\n")
      end

    end
  end
end
```

### Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :patient_for_contact do

    sequence (:patient_id) { |n| (121+n) }
    birth_date { FFaker::Time.date }
    gender { ["M","F"].sample }
    weight { rand(15.0...120.9).round(1) }
    height { rand(80...220).round(0) }
    bmi { rand(15.0...120.9).round(1) }

    injury_id { Injury.all.ids.sample } # gestisco manualmente
    physio_center_code { (PhysioCenter.all.empty?)? create(:physio_center).code : PhysioCenter.first.code } # Il PhysioCenter non viene creato!
  end

  factory :invalid_patient_for_contact, parent: :patient_for_contact do |f|

    f.gender nil
    f.injury_id nil
  end
end
```

### Results

```
1) Api::V1::PatientsController with right email and authentication_token PUT #update patient with wrong attributes doesn't change the attributes of the patient
     Failure/Error: expect(not_updated_patient.attributes).to eq(patient.attributes) #--> FAIL

       expected: {"id"=>2, "patient_id"=>123, "physio_center_id"=>2, "birth_date"=>Sun, 09 Jan 2011, "gender"=>"F", "weight"=>25.3, "height"=>105, "bmi"=>22.9, "injury_id"=>8, "created_at"=>Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:29 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:29 UTC +00:00}
            got: {"id"=>2, "patient_id"=>123, "physio_center_id"=>2, "birth_date"=>Sun, 09 Jan 2011, "gender"=>"F", "weight"=>25.3, "height"=>105, "bmi"=>22.9, "injury_id"=>8, "created_at"=>Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:30 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:30 UTC +00:00}

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
        "bmi" => 22.9,
       -"created_at" => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:29 UTC +00:00,
       +"created_at" => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:30 UTC +00:00,
        "gender" => "F",
       @@ -9,6 +9,6 @@
        "physio_center_id" => 2,
       -"updated_at" => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:29 UTC +00:00,
       +"updated_at" => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 13:03:30 UTC +00:00,
        "weight" => 25.3,
```

Note: sometimes *Diff* is empty.

It seems that there are some errors in the `created_at` and `updated_at` comparison. I'don't understand why there are different values. 
I select from the DB the same resource...

I've also tried with

```
expect(not_updated_patient).to have_attributes(patient.attributes)
```

but it fails too.

My development env:

- Ruby 2.2.0
- Rails 4.2.0
- FactoryGirl (4.5.0)
- rspec (3.2.0)
- rspec-core (3.2.3)
- rspec-expectations (3.2.1)
- rspec-rails (3.2.1)
- DatabaseCleaner (1.4.1)
- mysql2 (0.3.18)
- spring (1.3.6)
- spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same you should pick a set off attributes to compare. The `updated_at` and `created_at` differ.

Perhaps?

```
expect(not_updated_patient.attributes.without('updated_at', 'created_at')).to eq(patient.attributes.without('updated_at', 'created_at'))
```

using this [helper](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/delete#1403-Another-Hash-without)

```
class Hash
  def without(*keys)
    cpy = self.dup
    keys.each { |key| cpy.delete(key) }
    cpy
  end
end
```

Comment: It works! Thanks.

I noticed that `updated_at` and `created_at` differ, but I don't understand why? I pick the **same record from the db** and the update action fails, so doesn't change the attributes. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: A little note to your answer.
The `keys` of the returned hash by the method "attributes" are of type string, not symbol. 
So you must use  `.without("updated_at", "created_at")`

references: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes